# NodePort Service for http/2 with TLS backend does not work

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress, http2

I have a backend app which implements RESTful APIs over **http/2**. My requirement is to expose the backend service to the host network and I do it using `NodePort`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gold-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: gold-app
  ports:
  - name: gold-port
    port: 12349
    nodePort: 32349
  type: NodePort
```

When the app runs without TLS, the service is accessible as expected from outside the cluster. However, when the app runs with TLS, the service is no longer accessible. I observe from packet capture that the TLS handshake begins but does not conclude successfully.

```
$ curl https://10.225.68.106:32349/api/v1/config -kv --cert <cert file> --key <key file>
* About to connect() to 10.225.68.106 port 32349 (#0)
*   Trying 10.225.68.106...
* Connected to 10.225.68.106 (10.225.68.106) port 32349 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate from file
*       subject: ...
*       start date: Mar 29 07:10:42 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 26 07:10:42 2028 GMT
*       common name: ...
*       issuer: ...
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

I have gone through the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55028512/supporting-ssl-tls-for-a-kubernetes-nodeport-service). Is `Ingress` the only solution? Furthermore,  I am curious to know how and why NodePort is not able to handle http/2 TLS traffic.

Comment: Sorry that I can't give a sure answer; but from my experience (on HTTP/1.x) the only way to have TLS handling is by using an _Ingress_. Although maybe a properly configured web-server might be able to directly handle the TLS on requests coming to the NodePort. Using NGINX? Tried handling the TLS on it directly (https://cheapsslsecurity.com/p/how-to-enable-http-2-on-nginx/) ?

Comment: Thanks @Kamafeather for waking me up on this question - I almost forgot about it. The backend app I mentioned does  client authentication using certificates. In my case the app was not able to validate the certificate and got stuck there, without sending a proper response. So to summarize - yes, a properly configured web server (HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2) is able to directly handle TLS requests coming to the NodePort.

Comment: Ah great, glad that it worked out! I don't have experience in setting up TLS on webservers (am too lazy to handle certificates ), apart for tls on K8s ingresses, so happy to hear confirmation about the NodePort possibility, I was wondering the same couple weeks ago 